# How to generate sequences from different sets

Tags: python, list, generator

So I've got a series of sets of elements, like this:

```
elements= {
 'a' : '12345',
 'b' : '67890',
 'c' : 'abcdefg',
 'd' : 'hijklmn',
 ...
}
```

And what I want to do is have a function that takes in a definition of output and returns all possible combinations of characters from the sets above that match that definition.

For example, if the function received `'abbc'`, then it would return the set of all strings that have one character from set a, followed by a character from set b, followed by a character from set b, followed by a character from set c.

Ideally, this would return a generator.

Where I'm struggling is how to build the loop that goes over the input characters, selects the proper set from `elements`, then generates all combinations of all previous inputs.

for example, if I simply loop over the input, like this, how do I get the next sequence?

```
for c in list(input):
    element_set = list(elements[c])
    #now I've got the list of elements for this character, but how do I combine all possible values here with all possible values for the next character?
```

I could build a list of lists where I end up with the following:

```
[ list(elements[a]), list(elements[b]), list(elements[b]), list(elements[c]) ]
```

but then how do I grab the "all possible values of position 0" + "all possible values of position 1", etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ever-helpful [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) for this:

```
>>> elements = {'a': '12', 'b': '67', 
                'c': 'ab', 'd': 'hi'} # shortened example; 875 answers otherwise!
>>> s = 'abbc'
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for t in product(*[elements[c] for c in s]):
    print t


('1', '6', '6', 'a')
('1', '6', '6', 'b')
('1', '6', '7', 'a')
('1', '6', '7', 'b')
('1', '7', '6', 'a')
('1', '7', '6', 'b')
('1', '7', '7', 'a')
('1', '7', '7', 'b')
('2', '6', '6', 'a')
('2', '6', '6', 'b')
('2', '6', '7', 'a')
('2', '6', '7', 'b')
('2', '7', '6', 'a')
('2', '7', '6', 'b')
('2', '7', '7', 'a')
('2', '7', '7', 'b')
```

Comment: I had even looked into itertools.  But, of course I missed this.  Now I feel dumb, haha.